# Foreign Keys in Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Not so much a problem but a question about best practice and what will work for me in the future.

I have a number of tables which contain data that are linked to accounts in my schema - services, locations, providers, etc.

I have two choices, I can add a foreign key to accounts to all of my tables which will reduce the number of joins needed, but potentially will add to the data stored and (maybe?) lead to inconsistencies.

So, my question is, should I add an accounts FK to services, locations, etc. or rely on joins to manage that for me?

Comment: Foreign keys and the number of joins have nothing to do with each other. Furthermore, foreign keys are there to ensure data integrity. I do not really understand how adding more of them would lead to inconsistencies in data. Your question is really not clear to me.

Comment: Why would you want to carry redundant data that could possibly lead to inconsistencies? The number of joins really isn't an important metric. If you're concerned about performance, benchmark the normalized design and see what you can achieve with indexing.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structure of your databases it's hard to give a correct answer.  But let's take a single table `providers` for example.  If a provider can only have one account, then I would add a FK to the `providers` table.  If this is not the case then I would not use a FK because it wouldn't work.

Foreign Keys are to relate things together so there is no inconsistency.  So if you had an `employees` table and a `departments` table, `employees` would have a FK to `departments` because an employee can only be in one department.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some trouble understanding FK's and what they give you.

Your FK should join to a table with a PK (primary key) and this ensures data integrity between the tables.

However if you do not index the columns of the FK, it will be an unindexed FK and this can lead to full table scans on your joins.

PK's and FK's are merely constraints and do not add to storage.  Indexing a FK adds to storage, but the performance benefits of indexes usually outweigh the overhead of storage.

Using PK's and indexed FK's are all part of normalized data design and you should not have concerns in using them.